# Weather robot on Facebook using Bluemix results in 404 error

Tags: ibm-cloud, weather, weather-api

I created a weather robot on Facebook, but it showed the following error message:

```
404 Not Found: Requested route ('circle-weather-bot.mybluemix.net') does not exist.
```

Comment: There is literally no way anyone but you can answer this question right now. Give a [mcve], please.

Comment: is there no code? Or you have any code?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not binding your server to the port specified in the`PORT` environment variable, or your app is crashing before starting the server.

To bind to the port environment variable, use `app.set('port', process.env.PORT)`

Source: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/181713/404-not-found-requested-route-prodstat09mybluemixn/#